# Python / Pytest: how test a CLI command?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a simple class with Flask_restx:

```py
from flask_restx import Namespace, Resource

from flask import current_app

ping_namespace = Namespace("ping")


class Ping(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {
            "status": "success",
            "message": "system up and running",
            "api_version": current_app.config["APP_VERSION"],
        }

    def pingFromCommand():
        print(current_app.config["APP_VERSION"])


ping_namespace.add_resource(Ping, "")
```

This is the simple command in manage.py

```py
[...]
app = create_app()
cli = FlaskGroup(create_app=create_app)

from project.batch.v2.ping.ping import Ping

@cli.command('ping')
def ping():
    Ping.pingFromCommand()
```

If I run from command line, I get the desiderated result:

```sh
(env) $ python manage.py ping
(env) $ 2.0.0
```

I know how write tests for API resources with pytest, but I don't know how can I write a test for the `pingFromCommand` method.

I did try:

```py
from project.batch.v2.ping.ping import Ping

def test_ping_command(test_app):
    assert Ping.pingFromCommand() == "0.0.0"
```

But I get

```sh
>       assert Ping.pingFromCommand() == "0.0.0"
E       AssertionError: assert None == '0.0.0'
E        +  where None = <function Ping.pingFromCommand at 0x7fd41c619160>()
E        +    where <function Ping.pingFromCommand at 0x7fd41c619160> = Ping.pingFromCommand
```

Someone can help me or address me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the `pingFromCommand` function, `print` is used to print the current app version. That function returns `None` which is what you get in the `AssertionError`.

You can update the function to `return` the app version

```
def pingFromCommand():
    return current_app.config["APP_VERSION"]
```

Or you might be able to use `capsys` fixture provided by `pytest` which will capture
standard output:

```
def test_ping_command(capsys, test_app):
    Ping.pingFromCommand()
    captured = capsys.readouterr()  # Capture output
    assert captured.out == "0.0.0"  # Assert stdout
```